# Coordinates by odometer distance

Tags: r

In a vector which is an oil line, as you can imagine, and it's not a straight line, how can I get the coords X,Y given the distance? Eg.: What is the coord in position 400m from the beginning of the line.

```
> class(shp) #oil line, where each observation in my dataset ocurred
```

[1] "SpatialLinesDataFrame"

```
> class(dataset$posicao) #column that contains the points in metric distance from the beginning of the line
```

[1] "numeric"

Answer (score 0):

```
library(rgeos)

gInterpolate(spgeom = "SpatialLinesDataFrame", d = distance)
```