# Defining start point from a SpatialLineDataFrame

Tags: r, spatial, rgeo

There's a SpatialLineDataFrame where It is needed to discover coordinates along it's extention by odometric position, e.g. what's the coordinate of the point 2525m from the beginning of the line?

I managed to do that, kind of, here: [Coordinates by odometer distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75995704/coordinates-by-odometer-distance)

But when I went to present it, R considered the start point as the opposite of what I needed it to be.

```
library(rgeos)

gInterpolate(spgeom = "SpatialLinesDataFrame", d = distance)
```

**Long story short: the max odometric distance is in the beginning and vice-versa.**

[image: Points marked by odometric position along the vector]

Comment: just use ```gInterpolate(spgeom = "SpatialLinesDataFrame", d = line_length - distance)```